# How to place the `UIColor` on `UIImage` at particular (X,Y) position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

I am trying to place `UIColor` on particular (X,Y) position of `UIImage`,

But not able to get it,

Here, My code looks like below,

Below method return me a `UIColor` from particular (X,Y) position of `UIImage`

```
- (UIColor *)isWallPixel:(UIImage *)image xCoordinate:(int)x yCoordinate:(int)y {

   CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
   const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

   int pixelInfo = ((image.size.width  * y) + x ) * 4; // The image is png

   UInt8 red = data[pixelInfo];         // If you need this info, enable it
   UInt8 green = data[(pixelInfo + 1)]; // If you need this info, enable it
   UInt8 blue = data[pixelInfo + 2];    // If you need this info, enable it
   UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];     // I need only this info for my maze game
   CFRelease(pixelData);

   UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f]; // The

  return color;
}


//Original Image, I get image pixels from this image.
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"];

//Need convert Image
UIImage *imagedata = [[UIImage alloc]init];

//size of the original image
int Width = image.size.width;
int height = image.size.height;

//need to get this size of another blank image
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, Width, height);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

for (int i = 0; i <Width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {

       //Here I got the Image pixel color from below highlighted method
        UIColor *colordatra = [self isWallPixel:image xCoordinate:i yCoordinate:j];
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [colordatra CGColor]);

        rect.origin.x = i;
        rect.origin.y = j;
        CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imagedata.CGImage);
        imagedata = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
}

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Please note that I want to functionality like get the `UIColor` from particular position and placed that `UIColor` on another blank image at same position.

With above code I am not able to get this, Please let me know where  I have done the mistake.

Hope, for favourable reply,

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

By using uiView you can do this one like that.Actually you are getting x,y,width and height

```
uiview *view = [uiview alloc]initwithframe:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
view.backgroundcolor =[UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f];
[self.YourImageView addsubview:view];
```